# TextField Caret Does Not Display in Actionscript 3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, textfield, caret

I am trying to display a text field that has text inside it, and display the flashing Caret at the end of the text.
I have tried the following:

Code:

```
// ti_title is my textField

stage.focus = ti_title;

ti_title.setSelection( ti_title.length, ti_title.length );
```

I have also tried:

```
// ti_title is my textField

ti_title.stage.focus = ti_title;

ti_title.setSelection( ti_title.length, ti_title.length );
```

The field is focused because I can type into it, but I do not see a Caret until I have started typing. This is not very good for usability.

I have even tried removing text then re-adding it and then setting the selection again, but still not working.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what I was doing wrong.

The orginal Textfield on the stage had a Font color of white. I changed the font color to Black and the caret appeared. It was just being hidden against the white background.

This code:

```
ti_title.stage.focus = ti_title;

ti_title.setSelection( ti_title.length , ti_title.length);
```

worked in displaying the caret.